# ImageMagick - batch file - Font does'n change

Tags: windows, imagemagick, command-line-arguments

I have this code in ImageMagick, it works except for changing the font. I tried all kinds of options, I don't understand what I could do to change the font to the font I want.

Besides that, how can I give opacity to ``-undercolor "#E70E0E"```?

```
magick convert 13.jpg  -fill white -undercolor "#E70E0E" -gravity Center -font "Comic Sans MS" -pointsize "75"  -annotate +0+5 "Title-text" -gravity Center -pointsize "25" -font "Calibri Light" -annotate +0+100 "SubTitle-Text" -crop 1920x1080+0+0 -scale 1920x1080+0+0 picture.jpg
```

thank you so much

Comment: In Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.  However, that likely won't make a difference.  What is your IM 7 version.

Comment: With IM you can specify almost any font by pointing to the font file itself, like `... -font "c:\fonts\fancy_font.ttf" ...`. I often keep a copy of the TTF font file in the working directory for a project, and read it into the command from there, so my script isn't dependent on the system's installed fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly missing dashes in the font names (`Calibri-Light`).

You can list the fonts known to IM using `magick identify -list font`.

Comment: indeed, IM has a limited list of fonts it supports... I didn't expect it. Thanks a lot for the advice. Worked. and yes, the dashes  is needed, anyway it shows you the correct title in cmd

Comment: I don't think its list is "limited". There are fonts installed system wide (that it sees) and those installed for specific apps (that only those apps can see).

Answer (score 0):

Just got into the same issue and xenoid's comment put me on the right path:

Imagemagick on my server was only listing fonts installed *system wide* and not those installed **per user**.
I uninstalled the font then right-clicked on the font file again, but selected "Install for all users" this time, and now Imagemagick sees it.

[image: Install for all users]

Hope it helps.

Vicne